# Display back button on toolbar on first screen of navigation graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying out androidx navigation component and have setup my activity with a toolbar a  container. I'm doing this in one of the intermittent screens of my app which has a lot of internal navigation/steps and I thought I could navigation arch component a try with this.

Since this is an intermittent screen, I want to display a back button on the toolbar from the first screen itself.

I've already setup the toolbar with the below code in the onCreate() method of my host activity,

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 }
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navHostFragment.getNavController());
```

I can see the back button/back arrow on the second screen of my graph but not on the first screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/listing">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listing"
        android:name=".ui.ItemsListingFragment"
        android:label="Items"
        tools:layout="@layout/items_listing" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/listToQuantity"
            app:destination="@id/quantity"
           />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/listToReason"
            app:destination="@id/reason"
            />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:name=".ui.ItemQuanitySelectionFragment"
        android:label="Items"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_quanity_selection" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/quantityToReason"
            app:destination="@id/reason"
            />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/reason"
        android:name=".ui.ItemReasonFragment"
        android:label="Items"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_item_reason">
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

What more changes do I need to make to add the back button on the toolbar right from the first step.

Answer (score 31):

As you noted, navigation component show back button on all destinations except top-level. It uses an `AppBarConfiguration` to determine which destinations are considered 'top-level'.

So you need to:
1) create AppBarConfiguration without top-level destinations
2) call a 3-argument version of `setupActionBarWithNavController`

```
AppBarConfiguration abc = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build();
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navHostFragment.getNavController(), abc)
```

To customise up button behavior on 'top-level' destination you can set fallback `OnNavigateUpListener` in your appbar configuration builder:

```
new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(listener).build()
```

*More info from sources:*
click on up button calles `NavigationUI.navigateUp(NavController, AppBarConfiguration)` which in turn calles `NavController.navigateUp()` which tries to pop the backstack. As it cannot pop back stack, it just does nothing and returns false. Your fallback listener will be called in that case.

Comment: yap, back button appears but doesn't know how to go back

Comment: @rguerra Added info about this

Comment: Thanks for your good search --> very specific .. works  with me after 8 hours of search

Comment: very well explained. Thanks

Comment: @rafaelasguerra I have issue that back button not showing. Can you help me out.

Answer (score 4):

The back button is displayed as `onSupportNavigateUp()` method return `true`.
You need to override `onSupportNavigateUp()` method.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)
        mNavController = getNavController();
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        //
        if (!(mNavController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp())) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling `setUpActionBarWithNavCntroller` you have to override the function `onSupportNavigateUp`, like this:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp() 
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- I created an interface to show/hide up button from the nav host activity.

```
    interface ShowUpButtonListener {
    fun showUpButton()
    fun hideUpButton()
}
```

2- Here is how the activity implements the interface methods to show/hide up button:

```
    override fun showUpButton() {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
    val listener = AppBarConfiguration.OnNavigateUpListener { navController.navigateUp() }
    val abc = AppBarConfiguration.Builder().setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(listener).build()
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, abc)
}


override fun hideUpButton() {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
}
```

3- Here the method in the activity when up button pressed. If in start destination, implement onBackPressed():

```
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.nav_host)
    if(!navController.navigateUp()){ // When in start destination
        onBackPressed()
    }
    return navController.navigateUp()
}
```

4- In a fragment create show up button listener property:

```
private lateinit var showUpButtonListener: ShowUpButtonListener
```

5- Assign property to context activity:

```
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if(context is ShowUpButtonListener){
        showUpButtonListener = context
    }
}
```

6- In the fragment call hide or show up button from the interface property:

```
fun someFunction() { 
    showUpButtonListener.showUpButton()
}
```

7- In a fragment can listen whenever back button (NOT up button) pressed:

```
    private fun setupBackPress() {
    requireActivity()
        .onBackPressedDispatcher
        .addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() { 
            }
        })
}
```