# Android Navigation Drawer intercept arrow back button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

I'm using the latest JetPack implementations for my Android app and I need to conditionally navigate back from one of my fragments based on a logic.

I found this exquisite piece of code: `requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback()` in which I added my logic.

But it only works if I'm pressing the back button (either physical or virtual) of the phone. If I click the navigation arrow that appears in place of the hamburger when a navigation occurred, this method isn't called.

Is it possible to manage in a fragment also this event?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have used this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951871/display-back-button-on-toolbar-on-first-screen-of-navigation-graph for one of my project.

Comment: @tiborK sorry for being late. Thanks for your comment. Could you please make it an answer with a little bit of explanation so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetPack menages the fragments for you so you don't have to write all that boilerplate logic. Additional information on fragments can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

As mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951871/display-back-button-on-toolbar-on-first-screen-of-navigation-graph), navigation component will show back button on all destination except on "top-level".
You noted that when clicking on the back button, nothing happens. You can create a fallback listener like:

```
new AppBarConfiguration.Builder().setFallbackOnNavigateUpListener(listener).build()
```

To better understand why you need a fallback listener is because the back button press calls the NavigationUI.navigateUp(...) which calls the NavController.navigateUp() that tries to pop the fragment from the backstack. If there is nothing to pop it will return false and your fallback listener will be called.